# Creating partition function for Quicksort in python

Tags: python, quicksort

Hi I am not able to create partition function for quicksort in python. I've searched on many websites but am not able to understand what is going on. I tried to do it but am stuck here.

```
totalElem = input("Enter total Elements: ")
c = 0
unsortElem = [0]*totalElem
low = 0
high = totalElem - 1

# This is to input elements
for c in range(totalElem):
    unsortElem[c] = input("Enter Number: ")
    c += 1

# The swap function
def swap(elem1, elem2):
    k=elem1
    elem1 = elem2
    elem2 = k

def partition(list, low, high):
    left = low
    right = high
    pivot = (low+high)/2
    pivotElem = list[pivot]
    while(left<right):
        while(list[left]<pivotElem):
            left += 1
        while(list[right]>pivotElem):
            right += 1
        if(list[left]>list[right]):
            swap(left, right)


#The below prints are just to check if the function is getting correct values.
    print list
    print pivotElem
    print left
    print len(list)



partition(unsortElem, low, high)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code - firstly, your `right += 1` is wrong, since right is the highest index. You need to decrease the value, not increase. Secondly, why are you increasing `c` in input? You are using `range`, so it does it automatically. Also, you don't need your own swap function, since Python can do it, and `list` is a type, so you can't name your variable like that.

What you are trying to do is recursively sort elements smaller and bigger than your pivot. If you find larger element on the beginning of the list than pivot, you stop, the same for smaller element from the end of the list, then you swap the values (since they are in bad parts of your list). You also need to take care if there are more same elements. Your partition function doesn't do only partitioning, since you are swapping elements there, it's more like not correct quicksort function without recursive calls.

```
totalElem = int(raw_input("Enter total Elements: "))
unsortElem = []

# This is to input elements
for c in range(totalElem):
    unsortElem.append(int(raw_input("Enter Number: ")))

def qsort(mylist, low, high):
    if high - low < 1:   # there is less than 2 elements
        return
    left = low
    right = high
    pivotElem = mylist[(low + high) / 2]
    while left <= right:
        while mylist[left] < pivotElem:
            left += 1
        while mylist[right] > pivotElem:
            right -= 1
        if left <= right and mylist[left] >= mylist[right]:
            mylist[left], mylist[right] = mylist[right], mylist[left]
            left += 1
            right -= 1
    qsort(mylist, low, right)
    qsort(mylist, left, high)


qsort(unsortElem, 0, len(unsortElem) - 1)
print unsortElem
```

You didn't mention if you are using Python 3 or Python 2. This is corrected for Python 2, if you want it for Python 3, just use `input` instead of `raw_input` and braces for printing, eg `print(unsortElem)`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my mistakes. As I am just beginning so I'm making silly mistakes. I didn't quite understand statements after last if. Can you clarify a little what they do. I am using python 2.

Comment: Ok I got it after last if. It's swapping the elements.Thanks Adalee. I spent 2-3 hours on this and was going nowhere. And now that I see your neat program it looks so easy ;p. Can you give a few tips on how do I get better. I couldn't even write this program looking at quicksort algorithm psedocodes on wikipedia :(

Comment: If you are using Python 2, you don't need to do anything with the code, I just wrote there differences between it and Python 3, since I didn't know which one you use. To get better, just try writing code and then check if it can be improved. And since Python is not the same as pseudocode, it'd be better to understand *what* you are trying to write instead of retyping pseudocode, then you'll find it much easier. Hope that helps ;)